# Is there any support available in Android to scan and read QR Code wihout using the zxing library?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

We can verify and read QR code using the zxing library. But is there any native API support available in Android? Or is there any other API or means to scan and read QR codes in Android?

Comment: What is your logic behind not using the Xing library? It is open source so you could take the code yourself then your technically not reliant on 'the library'

Comment: Do you mean zxing? Although the whole zxing package is big, if you read the code, you will find that it could be tailor to a very small library.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support in Android to scan QR code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no alternative for reading Barcode except for using zxing library. You can use this alternative known as [biggu barcode scanner](http://bit.ly/scannerkitsdk-android-latest) which internally uses zxing library only. Or else you also have an other alternative i.e., Calling an Activity that can scan the QR Code. If no activity is not available then it redirects to Play store and installs one app. For the second option there is no requirement of zxing library too. This is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)